# drop links from xml inside a form

Tags: php, hyperlink, rss, channel

I have an xml file with RSS feed addresses. I want to build a dropdown list with those links and, when chosing an option, the feed should be displayed. I have build an xml with feeds(feeds.xml), which will be loaded in a variable.
This is the file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <channel xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <item>
              <link  xlink:show="new" xlink:href="http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1424">Web Design Sprite Sheet CSS Preload Graphics Tutorial</link>

       </item>

       <item>
              <link xlink:href="http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1423">Character Walk Cycle keyframes Sprite Animation CSS Tutorial</link>

        </item>
 </channel>
```

And....here is the php code:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('feeds.xml');
echo "<h2>Dropdown feeds</h2>";
echo "<form name='feeds'>";
echo "<select name='menu' id='menu' OnChange='location.href=feeds.menu.options[selectedIndex].value'>";
echo "<option value='' selected>Select feed...</option>";
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
$link = $xml->item[$i]->link;
    echo "<option value=$link>$link </option>";
}   
echo "</select>";


?>
```

The list is populated, but when select in item an error message occurs :((
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<option value="' . $link . '">' . $link . '</option>';
```

?

And more this for get values of attributes: php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: Ok, but when clicking on an item inside the control an error occurs(This program cannot display the webpage)